# Ask about kabbalah and reincarnation

Tags: death, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar, practical-kabbalah, reincarnation

I confused about reincarnation and many people from other religions have the stigma that the concept of Jewish reincarnation is only made up by rabbi issac luria and it is just an ordinary human creation.

1. "are ancient Jewish especially those born before Christ know and accept the concept of reincarnation ?"
2. What it is true that reincarnation is only made new by human thought especially by rabbi issac luria ?
3. Do the majority of jews or all jews must be believe in reincarnation?

Comment: Reincarnation is almost definitely a kabbalistic belief, however there are pre-Lurianic sources for it.

Comment: Fwiw I've noticed a lot in life that people discover that Judaism has a source for reincarnation, they are initially appalled, try to show how it can't be true, and end up accepting it in the end. Anecdotal but I've seen it a lot. The truth is, in the orthodox world at least, it's very widely accepted.